# Варианты звука О в диалектах

Tags: диалекты, фонетика, правила

Мой вопрос - на картинке.

[image: задание, помогите, нужна помощь! :с..........]

нужна помощь.

Comment: Есть догадка, но я пасую в отношении 2). Подождем Людмилу. Если она догадается, то я прав.

Comment: Да, это на какой уровень рассчитано?  Неужели ЕГЭ?)))

Comment: Да нет, @behemothus, не может такого быть, чтоб ЕГЭ.

Answer (score 1):

Сформулировать я затрудняюсь. )

О1. Двор, завод, клоп, пророк, поп.

О2. Комок, мозг, песок, рог, ход.

Comment: Ну это просто случайным образом раскинуто...

Comment: Да, как-то странно, что Вы правило сказать не можете, хотя как-то расположили. Хотелось бы узнать всё-таки настоящий ответ!

Comment: Для односложных слов: в О1 попадают те, у кого в косвенных падежах ударение переходит на окончание. Для двусложных: в О2 попадают слова с беглой О. Примерно так.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, ребята, я пас. Честно говоря, даже не хотела отвечать на вопрос. Автор поленился напечатать слова, переслал картинку: печатайте сами, вам делать нечего, у него под рукой лекции по диалектологии, у нас нет, а мы должны ломать голову.

Кстати,я терпеть не могла диалектологию, вокализм особенно, он очень непоследователен, поэтому здесь действительно нужна догадка и попытка произнести. Я попробую вас натолкнуть, а вы быстрее ответите. Правил на самом деле не существует,  в разных говорах по-своему, а то и одно слово по-разному произносится,их нужно сочинить, обращая внимание на фонетическое соседство согласных в таблице. Помочь может и падение редуцированных:там, где был Ъ, а сейчас беглый гласный, там только открытый гласный О1: песок, комок,

все старославянские заимствования и праславянского происхождения, если ударение не переносится на предлог -закрытый оу-О2: дв(оу)р, зав(оу)д

Но это настоящие правила, а здесь нужна догадка,голова в эту сторону не очень работает. И времени нет на эти игрушки. Я бы просто наугад отнесла к дифтонгическому закрытому "оу"ещё пророк, ход.

Answer (score 0):

А ведь Niemand, пожалуй что, прав. Я немножко не так думал, поэтому свой вариант обнародовать не буду.

Окончательно:

*В О2 относятся слова, у которых ударение переходит на флексию тогда и только тогда, когда в исходной форме ударное О - беглый гласный. 
В О1 - все остальные случаи, т.е. когда не смещается, или смещается, но не под влиянием беглости.*

Правда, к диалектологии это, похоже, не имеет отношения. Это задача лингвоматематическая, диалекты, скорее всего, выдуманы (=искусственно построены) в расчете на логику решающего.