# Суффикс "йот" как суффикс вторичной имперфективизации?

Tags: мёртвые-аффиксы, суффиксация

> ...то есть такой, с помощью которого глаголы, приобретшие совершенный
>   вид под влиянием приставки, возвращаются в несовершенный.

Где можно посмотреть, о чём вообще идет речь?!

Что за суффикс такой...  сакраментальный?!

Примеры, пожалуйста!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И где здесь суффикс "йот"? Дорисовывать, например. Дър'иесо́выэвът', где звук "э" в оригинале изображён как призвук. Но не ***-j-*** же!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Галина, здесь всё та же пресловутая йотовая палатализация.

Глаголы неоднократного действия зачастую образовывались от глаголов однократного действия.

Близить-несов. вид, добавляем  приставку - совершенный: сблизить, приблизить.

"а" - именно тот суффикс, который придаёт несовершенный вид,

-и- в йот перед гласной переходит регулярно,

[зj] -> [ж'] - как раз та самая   йотовая палатализация.

съблизити -> съблизиати -> съблизjати -> съближати .

Вот она и вторичная, вернулась к неоднократности исходного глагола несов вида близить = сближать

Потому вы йот и не видите, что он - только причина появления -Ж-. Есть чередование з/ж, д/ж,г/ж ... -значит, там поработал йот.

И без вторичной имперфектизации то же самое: родить - роди-а-ть - родjать – рожать.Здесь интересно, что есть и рождать. Всё дело в разных результатах палатализации. В южнославянских языках рефлекс "дj" дал "ж'д'", а в восточнославянских – "ж'". Т.о., глагол "рождать" имеет старославянские (церковнославянские) корни, а "рожать" – древнерусские.

Теперь понятно или полезем дальше в дебри науки, куда вы меня затащили?

Comment: Людмила, если времени и сил не жалко, продолжайте лезть. Я читаю вас с огромнейшим удовольствием.

Comment: Люсенька, я кое-что поняла, мне глубже нинада, а то крыша поедет! Пасибки! Но доставьте удовольствие Бегемотику из дома отдыха (так он сам обозначил место своего перманентного обитания). а я пока вульгарным макаром антивирус новый установлю...

Comment: Спасибо, дорогой  behemothus, из Ваших уст это уже похвала, а мне помнится, Вы как раз против научного мудрствования были, да и я не учёный, я ПРОСТО учитель на пенсии, а Вы с Галиной меня в науку теперь толкаете. А её вообще не понимаю, куда понесло, как она вышла на эти вопросы. Сайты-то все научные, для студентов. Мы вроде бы вышли из этого возраста.

Comment: Хотя у меня тоже был такой период, когда из комнаты не выходила и боялась , что настанет тупоумие, искала вопросы по языкознанию и пыталась ответить.Тоже по всем сайтам  бегала и радовалась, когда выпускники-студенты приходили со  своими  контрольными - мозги тренировала.

Comment: behemothus, а что это вы с Сержем не стали студенту помогать задание по диалектологии делать?http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/419530/%D0%   У вас логика мужская, вы оба справитесь быстро, а у меня даже желания нет, но я же вроде вас натолкнула на мысль, теперь уж Вам-то легко должно быть. А я всё смотрю, кто сделает.